# Invalid info_hash (Java BitTorrent client)

Tags: java, sha1, bittorrent

according to the specification: http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification

> info_hash: urlencoded 20-byte SHA1 hash of the value of the info key from the Metainfo file. Note that the value will be a bencoded dictionary, given the definition of the info key above.

`torrentMap`  is my dictionary, I get the `info` key which is another dictionary, I calculate the hash and I `URLencode` it.

But I always get an `invalid info_hash` message when I try to send it to the tracker.

This is my code:

```
    public String GetInfo_hash() {
    String info_hash = "";

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = null;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(torrentMap.get("info"));
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();        //Map => byte[]

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        info_hash = urlencode(md.digest(bytes));  //Hashing and URLEncoding

        out.close();
        bos.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {        }

    return info_hash;
}

private String urlencode(byte[] bs) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(bs.length * 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < bs.length; i++) {
        int c = bs[i] & 0xFF;
        sb.append('%');
        if (c < 16) {
            sb.append('0');
        }
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(c));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly the problem:

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
out.writeObject(torrentMap.get("info"));
```

What you're going to be hashing is the *Java binary serialization format* of the value of `torrentMap.get("info")`. I find it very hard to believe that all BitTorrent programs are meant to know about that.

It's not immediately clear to me from the specification what the value of the "info" key is meant to be, but you need to work out some other way of turning it into a byte array. If it's a string, I'd expect some well-specified encoding (e.g. UTF-8). If it's already binary data, then use that byte array directly.

EDIT: Actually, it's sounds like the value will be a "bencoded dictionary" as per your quote, which looks like it will be a string. Quite how you're meant to encode that string (which sounds like it may include values which aren't in ASCII, for example) before hashing it is up for grabs. If your sample strings are all ASCII, then using "ASCII" and "UTF-8" as the encoding names for `String.getBytes(...)` will give the same result anyway, of course...

Comment: **torrentMap.get("info")** returns an Object and it is castable to an HashMap. according on what you said I change the method into:  **return urlencode(torrentMap.get("info").toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));**    but it still gives me something wrong :(

Comment: @Simone: Well if it's *really* a `HashMap`, you need to get it into a `String` in bencoding form - because that's what will be hashed. It's unclear whether you're trying to create your own BT API from scratch, or adapt an existing one - but you'll *need* bencoding support.